# Confusion regarding fundamental particles

Tags: particle-physics, elementary-particles

As per standard model, particles like electron and quarks are considered as the elementary particles (*no further division into simpler particles possible*). 
Are those particles really elementary or people don't have enough resources (*theories, instruments, energy*) to break them into simpler particles at present?

Comment: See also: [What are quarks made of?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16048/what-are-quarks-made-of)

Comment: Also [search this site for *preon*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=preon)

Comment: this is the same question as http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312280/what-is-might-be-the-basic-component-that-makes-up-elementary-particles/312469#312469 in which I have given you a link that shows the searches made experimentally which establish limits for compositenes. Have you looked at the link?  or the preon link?