# Particles and string theory

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, field-theory, string-theory, oscillators

In string theory, how are specific string states associated with specific particle species? How in particular is the photon described as a string?

Comment: This question (v4) seems quite broad.

Comment: "elastic multidimensional fabric and particles in it are just tensions or vibration" Sounds like open strings on a p-brane in M-theory, which also has closed-string particles such as gravitons. "we can merge conservation of mass with conservation of energy" We can already do that. "how scientists distinguish particles in it" The identification of specific string states with specific particle species is a great question for this site (which I wish I could answer for you), but to address @Qmechanic's concern I suggest you edit out everything else, which is more speculative and not on-topic here.

Comment: @Qmechanic Not at all. I just need someone to explain what is particles and everything else is just a background to help people understand question better.

Comment: Also, couldn't fit this in my last comment, but welcome to Physics SE. ([Love the allusion in your username, by the way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant).)

Comment: @J.G. Thank you :) So you suggest to remove this question and recreate it?

Comment: No, it just needs editing down. I've made an example edit, but feel free to tweak if it still doesn't get at what you want. The important point is questions here should be about already mainstream physics, which includes string theory but not your elastic idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305760/50583

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thanks for that find. I notice you gave it an answer ending, "It is therefore unreasonable to expect a direct map between the physical idea of vibrations of the string and the states that the fully quantized theory will exhibit. Sorry."