# Question about the first two terms in the mode expansion in string theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

I am confused about the mode expansion in string theory. For instance, for a bosonic closed string, the field describing the string coordinates $X^\mu(\sigma,\tau)$ can be written as: (many thanks to @ACurousmind for writing it in an [answer to another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305760/how-are-string-vibration-modes-related-to-particle-identity/307315#307315))

$$X_\pm^\mu(\tau\pm\sigma) = \underbrace{\frac{x^\mu + c^\mu}{2}}_{\text{initial position}} + \underbrace{\frac{\pi\alpha'}{l}p^\mu(\tau\pm\sigma)}_{\text{center-of-mass motion}} + \underbrace{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}} \frac{\alpha^{\pm\mu}_n}{n}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}}{l}n(\tau\pm\sigma)}}_{\text{vibrational modes}}$$

If I am not wrong, the first two terms do not appear in QFT because the fields permeate the entire space, so there is no such thing as an observer “outside the field”, and thus there are no terms for a center of mass position or momentum of the entire field itself. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "the first two terms do not appear in QFT?"? This decomposition (probably copied from [my answer to a different question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/307315/50583), please cite your sources!) is fully general and already there in the classical (field!) theory of the string and remains if you just try to quantize it. The kinds of QFTs we usually look at are simply not the $\sigma$-model of the string, i.e. they have different equations of motions, so why would you expect to see such a decomposition there?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I did copy it from your question, but I didn't know you claimed the originality of such equation. I am sorry if I made you feel unrecognized.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I understand, I wrote the classical solution, my question is if those two terms appear in QFT, I have a low IQ and could not find them, so if you know of any reference in which they appear, please share it.

Comment: 1. I don't claim originality (variants of this should appear in every intro text to string theory); but if you copy something verbatim, you should cite the source. 2. It's still not clear to me what you mean by the terms "appearing in QFT". QFT usually uses different actions than the action of the $\sigma$-model of the string, so why would the solution to the classical equation of motion of the string have any relevance in QFT?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I dont think they have, I am just being cautions in claiming that they do not appear (and I believe the reasons they do not appear are the ones in the question).  I need to be sure I am not wrong, to write a follow up question without a shower of downvotes, as people here seem to get stressed and frustrated when the OP is confused.

Comment: I don't get offended by downvotes, but unfortunately people who could be helpful pay less attention to downvoted questions